# Переход между display none и block, на чистом JS

Tags: javascript, css3

Мне нужно реализовать плавный переход, от NONE к BLOCK. Изучая примеры никак не могу понять, как сделать это на чистом JS, везде примеры на jquery.

css:

```
.slide {
   display: none;
   position: absolute;
   opacity: 0;
   list-style: none;
}

.show {
   display: block;
   position: relative;
   opacity: 1;
}
```

js:

```
var slide = document.getElementById('slider');
var slides = slide.getElementsByTagName('div');
var currentSlide = 0;


function leftBtn() {
    slides[currentSlide].className = 'slide';
    currentSlide = (++currentSlide)%slides.length;
    slides[currentSlide].className = 'slide show';
}

function rightBtn() {
    slides[currentSlide].className = 'slide';
    currentSlide = (--currentSlide + slides.length) % slides.length;
    slides[currentSlide].className = 'slide show';
}
```

Comment: Переход от `display:none` к `display:block` не анимируется. Плавности нужно добиваться другими средствами.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko это я знаю, но не представляю как это можно сделать. Отказаться от display вообще я так же не могу.

Comment: Вообще отказаться от него можно. Конкретная реализация зависит от вашей `html` разметки, а также от задачи. Какого рода анимацию вы хотите?

Comment: тема обсуждалась на css можно реализовать https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8449933/animation-css3-display-opacity

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko Мне нужен просто плавный переход с opacity 0 to 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ взят из  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8449933/animation-css3-display-opacity

```css
.slide-wrapper {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.slide-wrapper .slide {
  display: none;
}

.slide-wrapper:hover .slide {
  display: block;
  animation: fadeInFromNone 1s ease-out;
}

@keyframes fadeInFromNone {
  0% {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  1% {
    display: block;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="slide-wrapper">
  <div class="slide">
    1
  </div>
</div>
<div class="slide-wrapper">
  <div class="slide">
    2
  </div>
</div>
<div class="slide-wrapper">
  <div class="slide">
    3
  </div>
</div>
```